# How would I transform an object of boolean values for use with Angular Material multi-select?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material2

How would I transform the following object (retrieved from my endpoint) to initialize an Angular Material 2, Multi-select form field:

**Object from API:**

```
roles = {
    admin: false,
    user: true,
}
```

**Template:**

```
<mat-select formControlName="roles" required multiple [compareWith]="compareRoles">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let role of roleList" [value]="role">{{role}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**FormGroup:**

```
createForm(): FormGroup
{
    return this._formBuilder.group({
        roles : [[this.roles]],
    });
}
```

**compareWith function:**

```
public compareRoles(c1: any, c2: any): boolean {
    return c2[0].hasOwnProperty(c1) && c2[0][c1]
}
```

---

For some reason, I keep getting the following error:

```
"Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined"
```

What am I missing? I just want the multi-select box to be pre-filled with the data from the API.

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
public compareRoles(c1: any, c2: any): boolean {
  if (c2 && c2[0]) {
    return c2[0].hasOwnProperty(c1) && c2[0][c1];
  }
  return false;
}
```

it should silence the error. You can add a `debugger` statement before returning false to figure out why c2[0] isn't defined (without a full working demo, it's somewhat difficult to diagnose).